# Safari is not displaying display: grid

Tags: html, css, ios, safari

I am working on a project where I have to create a music selection. I have build one and it works perfect in Windows Chrome, Firefox, Opera as well as on my Android Phone Chrome and Firefox. Now I have been testing on Safari and that's where the problems started.
Specifically iOS Safari.

It behaves as if there were no `display: grid` available. My code is below, here are some screenshots as an example.

### This is what it is supposed to look like.

[image: Correct way]

### And this is how Safari displays it.

[image: Wrong way]

I don't know how to fix that. I have tried to look for an answer online, or try fixed widths, but it does nothing. Here's the code:

```css
.music-selection-container {
  background: yellow;
  width: 886px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.music-selection-header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 100px 559px 60px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: blue;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.music-selection-header-mobile {
  display: none;
}

.music-selection-header>div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.music-selection-header .number {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

.music-selection-header .title {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.music-selection-header .length {
  grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 5;
}

.music-selection-list {
  height: 229px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.music-entry {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 100px 559px 60px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
}

.music-entry>* {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.music-entry .play {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  background: none;
  color: blue;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.music-entry .list-number {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
}

.music-entry .title {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.music-entry .length {
  grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 5;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.music-entry .add {
  grid-area: 1 / 5 / 2 / 6;
  background: none;
  color: blue;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  .music-selection-container {
    width: 375px;
    height: 526px;
    background: white;
    padding: 17px 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .music-selection-header {
    display: none;
  }
  .music-selection-header-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .music-selection-container .search {
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    background: white;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
    border-radius: 39px;
    border: none;
    padding: 15px;
    color: black;
  }
  .music-selection-container .music-selection-title {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .music-selection-list {
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .music-entry {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 28px 237px 55px 36px;
    grid-template-rows: 40px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .music-entry>* {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: auto;
  }
  .music-entry .play {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
    background: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: auto;
  }
  .music-entry .list-number {
    display: none;
  }
  .music-entry .title {
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: auto;
  }
  .music-entry .length {
    grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: auto;
  }
  .music-entry .add {
    grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 5;
    width: auto;
    background: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

.music-selection-footer {
  height: 65px;
  padding: 0 14px;
  border-top: 4px solid var(--light-gold);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.music-selection-footer button {
  padding: 8px 28px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="music-selection-container">
  <div class="music-selection-header">
    <div class="number">Nr.</div>
    <div class="title">Titel</div>
    <div class="length">Länge</div>
  </div>
  <div class="music-selection-header-mobile">
    <input type="search" name="search" class="search" placeholder="Search..." />
    <h4 class="music-selection-title">Music:</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="music-selection-list">
    <div class="music-entry">
      <button class="play"><i class="fas fa-play">P</i></button>
      <span class="list-number">1.</span>
      <span class="title">Christmas Magic Chords</span>
      <span class="length">02:11</span>
      <button class="add"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle">+</i></button>
    </div>

    <div class="music-entry">
      <button class="play"><i class="fas fa-play">P</i></button>
      <span class="list-number">1.</span>
      <span class="title">Christmas Magic Chords</span>
      <span class="length">02:11</span>
      <button class="add"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle">+</i></button>
    </div>

    <div class="music-entry">
      <button class="play"><i class="fas fa-play">P</i></button>
      <span class="list-number">1.</span>
      <span class="title">Christmas Magic Chords</span>
      <span class="length">02:11</span>
      <button class="add"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle">+</i></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="music-selection-footer">
    <button>A</button>
    <button>B</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tested this everywhere in safari browser and ios devices.. its working fine. Which version of ios or safari browser you are facing this issue?

Comment: I use Kobiton to test it on Safari, which offers iPhone 6s Plus with iOS 10.1.

Comment: depends what version of safari it runs, looks like iOS 10.1 has a 9.x version. It got grid in version 10.3, https://caniuse.com/?search=grid

Comment: Well, that is unfortunate. So I can't rely on Kobiton for testing then.

Comment: Yea. In case you look for new testing tools you can use this for reference regarding safari versions, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627968/what-version-of-mobile-safari-comes-with-each-version-of-ios